# Getting blank console output (System.out.println not working)

Tags: java

Why am I getting blank from the console?

In this *first* *part* */ initial stage* of my assignment, I am simply trying to the computer to tell me what day of the week the user input according the corresponding integer (0 is Sunday, 1 in Monday, etc..).

```
/*
Write a program that prompts the user to enter an integer for today’s day of 
the week 
(Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, ..., and Saturday is 6). Also prompt the user to 
enter the 
number of days after today for a future day and dis- play the future day of 
the week. 
*/

import java.util.Scanner; //import scanner

public class Program{
    public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //create a scanner object

    int dayIntInput = input.nextInt(); //assign next integer input to dayInt

    System.out.println("What is today's corresponding integer (Sunday=0, Monday=1, etc...."); //ask user for integer

    String[] daysOfWeek = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"}; //make array of days of week

    String dayOfWeek = daysOfWeek[dayIntInput];

    System.out.println(dayOfWeek);

    }
}
```

Comment: I ran your code and it appears to be working... Maybe you entered a number out of bounds?

Answer (score 5):

You requested input **before** displaying the message to tell the user to enter something.  So when you run the program, it *looks like* it has just stopped cold.  In fact, it's waiting for you to type something.

A little rearranging of the code will make the program more user-friendly:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //create a scanner object
// Prompt user first...
    System.out.println("What is today's corresponding integer (Sunday=0, Monday=1, etc...."); //ask user for integer
// ... THEN accept input
int dayIntInput = input.nextInt(); //assign next integer input to dayInt
```

Comment: Good catch... going beyond the syntax to the semantics of the user's understanding. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to put that System.out.println before the line where you get user input (the nextInt() one)

Comment: Coldspeed, it fixed my problem completely

Comment: @David Did not even fathom that your problem was in your mind... :-)

Comment: Ah yes , this is wise :)